# iMac 21.5" Late 2009 and external monitor at 2560x1440 with MDP-DP cable?

Tags: imac, display

I just want to know if someone has tested if an external monitor works at 2560x1440 with an iMac 21.5" Late 2009 connected via Mini Displayport - Displayport cable. I can't find anything certain on the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple says it does:

[iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP576)

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to a 30-inch display (2560 by 1600 pixels) on an external display

A well made Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable should work just fine.